# when i start my bot it show conot find module

Tags: discord, discord.js

when i start my bot is throw an error Error: Cannot find module './Commands/fun/avatar.js'
Require stack:

- /home/runner/Flare-2/handler/command.js
- /home/runner/Flare-2/index.js

please help

```
const {readdirSync} = require('fs');
const ascii = require('ascii-table');
const table = new ascii('Commands');

table.setHeading('Command', 'Load status')

module.exports = (client) => {
  readdirSync('./Commands').forEach(dir => {
    const commands = readdirSync(`./Commands/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for(let file of commands){
      let pull = require(`./Commands/${dir}/${file}`);
      if(pull.name){
        client.commands.set(pull.name, pull);
        table.addRow(file, '✅ -> Commands Loaded')
      } else {
        tabel.addRow(file, '⛔ -> Commands Error')
        continue;
      }if(pull.aliases && Array.isArray(pull.aliases)) pull.aliases.forEach
      (alias => client.aliases.set(alias, pull.name))
    }
  })
   console.log(table.toString());
}
```

Comment: try replacing all `./Commands/` by `../Commands/` (add another dot after the first one)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `./Commands/` with `../Commands/`